# How do you install Gnome Software center?

Tags: gnome, software-center

I updated Ubuntu Gnome, Gnome version to 3.12 and was trying to figure out how to make categories within the application menu. I tried using the dconf-editor (org > gnome > shell : app-folder-categories) method, but the option isn't available in 3.12. The only way I've found that would allow you to make categories is through Gnome Software and so far I haven't been able to find a way of downloading it.

Answer (score 3):

Just type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: This installs it with a snap package

Comment: You can also install the flatpak plugin for the GNOME Software.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Gnome Software [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software).  Once downloaded expand the file, and look in the INSTALL file for information on how to install.  You have to build the file from source, or you can take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).  Basically the steps to follow are:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: The above link through a link shortener no longer works.