# Why is GNOME Software Center not included in Ubuntu GNOME (14.04/14.10)?

Tags: gnome, software-center, software-sources, ubuntu-gnome

So I installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 (which included GNOME 3.10) and noticed that [GNOME Software Center](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software) isn't included and isn't available through the repositories. Then I tried installing Ubuntu 14.10 (which included GNOME 3.12 stack) and, you guessed it, no GNOME Software center. Only the [Ubuntu Software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/).

Any idea why the devs didn't include it even as an option? Isn't Ubuntu GNOME meant to be a vanilla-GNOME-type-of-distro?

Comment: Ubuntu has never been a vanilla-something distro. Not sure where you got the idea.

Comment: Ubuntu-GNOME is meant to give a vanilla-GNOME stack with Ubuntu repositories. Adding GNOME Software is part of the choice here. "Ubuntu GNOME (formerly Ubuntu GNOME Remix) is a mostly pure GNOME desktop experience built from the Ubuntu repositories." (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME)

Comment: Key word being "mostly". Even the GNOME3 PPAs don't have the software centre, so why would the official repository have it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say it's because Ubuntu has it's own Software Center which is better then GNOME Software Center, in their opinion. Ubuntu GNOME FAQ says the following about it:

> **Why do you include Ubuntu Software Center instead of GNOME Software for installing software?**
>
> Ubuntu Software Center offers user ratings and reviews, screenshots, and better search. GNOME developers currently do not intend to support easy install of proprietary software like Steam or the Humble Indie Bundles.

Source: http://ubuntugnome.org/documentation/faq/

But I'm pretty sure there is a possibility to install it, even though I can't tell you how.

Comment: If there isn't a technical issue adding the GNOME Software into the repos., why isn't it simply there?

Comment: Mhm, that's a good question. Maybe there is a technical issue, because I didn't find an easy way to install it. I only found a build-it-from-source-answer on AskUbunut [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524984/how-do-you-install-gnome-software-center)

Comment: I think that the technical reason for not adding it to the repos is the fact that also Debian is not using it and, instead, it is using USC.

Comment: But then again there is the question why Debian is not using it, or doesn't provide it in the repositories.

Comment: gnome-software depends on epiphany, so you might also quote from the faq directly above the one you cite. Although epiphany in available, if they can't keep it up to date or backport new version of gtk3 and webkit, then I suppose gnome-software could break down the road.

Comment: I already linked this question

Answer (score 0):

Gnome SOftware Center will now be available on 16.04 release to replace the current software center. So probably you can install it now.